# Dictionary [String: String] keys order changed when converted to array swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary like below,

```
var dataSource: [String: String] = ["FirstName": "Austin",
                                    "ListName": "Michael",
                                    "Address": "Street Address",
                                    "City": "Chennai"]
```

I want to populate these values in a `UITableView`, so I tried to get all the `keys` from `Dictionary` to an `Array` like below,

```
let dataArray = Array(dataSource.keys)
```

I got the output as `[String]` like,

```
["LastName", "FirstName", "City", "Address"]
```

The problem is, the **order** of the keys has changed, I want the `array` in the same order as `dictionary` has.

Can you anyone help?

Comment: A dictionary has no order by definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use plain dictionary as tableview datasource is bad idea.

However `Dictionary` can not be sorted. So it doesn't matter in what order you add your keys-values to the dictionary.

If you need sorted then use array of dictionary instead.

You should use models instead of plain dictionary that is easy to maintain :]

like

```
struct User {

    var firstName:String?
    var lastName:String?
    var address:String?
    var city:String?
}
```

Comment: Actually I have 20 more fields that needs to be populated in Tableview, that's why I tried using Dictionary. Do have any simple way to do that?

Comment: @AustinMichael If you have more than 20 fields then you should use struct. it better then play with key - value. as well as typecasting etc.. . You can fill that struct from data you have . and you can maintain each property easily. You can also user Codable as well if you filling it from JSON