# How to pass Dictionary value to an Array?

Tags: ios, arrays, dictionary, swift3

```
var params = [[String:Any]]()

for i in 0 ..< QuesCount  {
    self.params.append([self.key1[i] : self.value1[i],
                            self.key2[i] : self.value2[i]])
}
```

Output:

```
self.params= [["answer[0][question_id]": "1", "answer[0][ans_id]": "21"], ["answer[1][question_id]": "2", "answer[1][ans_id]": "26"], ["answer[2][ans_id]": "36", "answer[2][question_id]": "5"], ["answer[3][ans_id]": "40", "answer[3][question_id]": "6"], ["answer[4][question_id]": "7", "answer[4][ans_id]": "41"], ["answer[5][question_id]": "8", "answer[5][ans_id]": "46"], ["answer[6][ans_id]": "49", "answer[6][question_id]": "9"], ["answer[7][question_id]": "10", "answer[7][ans_id]": "54"], ["answer[8][question_id]": "11", "answer[8][ans_id]": "57"]]
```

But the problem is that I want :

Desirable Output :

```
["answer[0][question_id]": "1", "answer[0][ans_id]": "21"], ["answer[1][question_id]": "2", "answer[1][ans_id]": "26"], ["answer[2][ans_id]": "36", "answer[2][question_id]": "5"], ["answer[3][ans_id]": "40", "answer[3][question_id]": "6"], ["answer[4][question_id]": "7", "answer[4][ans_id]": "41"], ["answer[5][question_id]": "8", "answer[5][ans_id]": "46"], ["answer[6][ans_id]": "49", "answer[6][question_id]": "9"], ["answer[7][question_id]": "10", "answer[7][ans_id]": "54"], ["answer[8][question_id]": "11", "answer[8][ans_id]": "57"]
```

How Can I obtain desirable Output??

Comment: Don't do this. Use Struct  or class see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51335757/dictionary-string-string-keys-order-changed-when-converted-to-array-swift/51335800#51335800

Comment: Your question does not make sense you need an array of dictionary which is what you are getting but in your desired output you want an array of dictionary without array???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not answer what you are asking as it not looks very convenient solution to me.

You should avoid using that complex structure of dictionary that will be very hard to manage in future.You can use `struct` or `class` as per your requirement that is easy and readable.

As I don't know your actual structure you are using so for just example 
For example

```
struct  Question {

   var questionID:String?
   var question:String?
   var answersOption:[Options]?

   var correctAnswer:Options?{
       return self.answersOption.filter{$0.isCorrectAnswer == true}
   } 


}

struct Options {
   var answerID:String?
   var answer:String?
   var isCorrectAnswer = false
}
```

Now you can create Array of questions and inside it you have options as well as correct answer; Cool right

Hope it is helpful

Answer (score -1):

You can get all the values by this way -

```
for i in 0 ..< params.count
{
     print(params[i] , terminator:",")
}
```

Comment: we don't fetch dictionary from array like that